# How can I create a variable through a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code

```
this_item = "1234"     
this_is_a_list = []
for item in this_is_a_list:
    if this_item == item:
        print("this item is already in the list")
    else:
        this_is_a_list.append(str(this_item))
        print("I want to create a new variable with the name of this_item")
```

What I want it to do is check if this_item is in this_is_a_list and if it is, do something like print "this item is already in the list", but if the item isn't in this_is_a_list, then I want to create a new variable named whatever this_item is equal to, the I want that variable to be equal 0. Just for context, this_item will likely change a lot.

Comment: I think you'll want [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary instead:

```
myDict = {}
this_item = "1234"     
this_is_a_list = []
for item in this_is_a_list:
    if this_item == item:
        print("this item is already in the list")
    else:
        #this_is_a_list.append(str(this_item))
        #print("I want to create a new variable with the name of this_item")
        myDict[str(this_item)] = 0
```

Later you can retrive values like:

```
print(myDict['1234'])
```